# What is the canon/standard name for file handle/stream/file stream of Lua?

Tags: file, lua, io, stream, handle

I noticed that the thing that is returned by `io.open()` is called differently. I wonder what the canon name is.

- in Lua 5.4 Reference Manual, it's called a "file handle".
- in "Programming in Lua" 4/e, it's called a "stream".
- I saw in Lua Users Wiki that is's called "file stream" (maybe not the only name used in that Wiki)

Lua Reference Manual should be official, but the book is written by a creator of the language, so both should be canon, yet they use different names.

What is the canon/standard name for it, if there is one? Can anyone provides information? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The language used to describe Lua is *heavily* influenced by its reference implementation language, C, which in turn has its language tied tightly with Unix. If  you want to dive down the rabbit hole, [everything is a file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file) and particularly [§7.19 Input/output](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) of the C99 standard are good places to start to see how intermingled the concepts of streams & files are.

Comment: And (@kietfsek) you forget/overseen in the enumeration: ```File descriptor``` ;-) - Maybe we can say: A file handler is a file descriptor to a byte stream - And therefore i think its OK to use them all to describe the 'All is a descriptor' thingy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Lua 5.4.6  Copyright (C) 1994-2023 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> io.stdin
file (0x7fff90c0bd90)
```

That's why the reference manual talks about *file handles*. A *handle* is an opaque pointer to an abstract object.
It's the same with tables:

```
> {}
table: 0x7f86056042d0
```

But you shouldn't need to worry about these details.
The terminology in *Programming in Lua* is probably chosen for an audience with diverse backgrounds, but I don't speak for the author.

Comment: The implementation probably uses C functions, and the thing I wondered is probably `FILE` (or `FILE *`) in C functions:

```
Lua 5.4.6  Copyright (C) 1994-2023 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> io.stdin
file (0x7f88a44479c0)
> type(io.stdin)
userdata
```

Guess there is no standard name for it, since when a person codes in Lua, they don't need to specifically name this thing in order to use it. While the reference talks more about technical details, hence it reflects the underlying implementation more, while the book being for beginners, explains things for the sake of education.